# How to upload files(images, pdf) using Azure blob storage with standard account?

Tags: nestjs, azure-blob-storage

I am using azure blob storage standard account. When I try to upload files, it throws the error 'BlobTypeNotSupported'. I know standard account doesn't support 'Block Blobs'. Is there any other way to upload files using standard account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**I tried in my environment and got below results:**

I created a standard storage account through azure portal :

[image]

I used the below code to upload images using nest.js

**Code:**

```
import { BlobServiceClient, BlockBlobClient } from  '@azure/storage-blob';
import { Injectable } from  '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export  class  AppService {
azureConnection = "< Connection string >";
containerName = "test";

getBlobClient(imageName:string):BlockBlobClient{
const  blobClientService = BlobServiceClient.fromConnectionString(this.azureConnection);
const  containerClient = blobClientService.getContainerClient(this.containerName);
const  blobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(imageName);
return  blobClient;
}

async  upload(file:Express.Multer.File){
const  blobClient = this.getBlobClient(file.originalname);
await  blobClient.uploadData(file.buffer);
}
}
```

**console:**

[image]

**Postman:**
You can use the post request to upload image via postman.

[image]

**Portal:**

The above request worked successfully and uploaded file through azure storage standard account using nest.js with Block-blob type.

[image]

**Reference:**

[NestJS API File Operations Using Azure Blob Storage (learmoreseekmore.com)](https://www.learmoreseekmore.com/2021/03/nestjs-api-file-operations-using-azure-blob-storage.html#:%7E:text=In%20this%20article,%20we%20are%20going%20to%20use,massive%20amount%20of%20file%20data%20as%20unstructured%20data.)
by Naveen.

Comment: thanks for your reply. but still am getting the same error

Comment: In portal, check whether you can upload files using **`Blockblob`** type in your standard storage account like this [screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/K1z0ff6.png)

Comment: issue resolved. problem with wrong container type. thanks.